# downloading data using python from a website that uses javascript to display information

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I typically use the following template script to download data from a website:

```
import urllib.request as web
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
url_to_visit ='http://www.website-link-to-download-data'
source_code =  web.urlopen(url_to_visit).read()
source_code = ''.join(map(chr, source_code)
source_code = source_code.split('\n')
## then further process the lines returned in `source_code` as needed
```

But sometimes I come across very difficult sites.

Consider the site: https://www.spice-indices.com/idp2/Main#home. Suppose from the first table `Intraday Alerts - United States`, I want to download via Python script the information that is displayed when I click the `SP TMI` tab.

I looked at the output of the `splitSource` above, but I couldn't figure out how to extract the information I want. It seems to be using Javascript backend to display the information. Can someone give me any pointers or suggestions?

I am using Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you activate the "SP TMI" tab there is a POST request send to "intraday-announcements.json" endpoint - simulate that in your code and parse the JSON response.

Sample working code using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.get("https://www.spice-indices.com/idp2/Main#home")

    response = session.post("https://www.spice-indices.com/idp2/intraday/effectivedate/11-14-2015/intraday-announcements.json", data={
        "start": "0",
        "limit": "10",
        "indexKey": "SPUSA-TMI-USDUF--P-US----"
    })

    data = response.json()["widget_data"]
    for item in data:
        print(item["EVENT_NAME"])
```

Prints:

```
Dividend
Weekly Share Change
Special Dividend
Merger/Acquisition
Merger/Acquisition
Drop
Merger/Acquisition
Merger/Acquisition
Drop
Identifier Changes
```

Note that the effective date is actually inside the URL, see the `11-14-2015` part.

Comment: one quick question for this page: `http://www.ftse.com/products/index-notices/home/getnotices/?id=GEISAC&title=`, how do I find the `json` or the equivalent `request`?

Comment: @uday glad to help. Just use browser developer tools and inspect what requests are made. After a quick look, I think there is a GET request made to `http://www.ftse.com/products/index-notices/Backend/GetNotices` endpoint that contains the list of notices on a page. If you have difficulties getting the desired data, consider making a new separate question so that more people can help. Thanks!